# Pymysql 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Could you please help check where is wrong with my SQL command? Thank you so much in advance.

The error is below.

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:57:41, Addressing API Vulnerabilities in Connected Car Services and Fleets, A' at line 1")

My SQL is below.

```
title=escape_string(filtered_content[0][1])
author=escape_string(filtered_content[0][2])
publishdate=escape_string(filtered_content[0][3])
content=escape_string(filtered_content[0][4])
tags=escape_string(filtered_content[0][5])
url=escape_string(filtered_content[0][6])
dt=escape_string(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
sql = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES (NULL, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}) FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {} WHERE url={}".format(self.tableName, dt, title, author, publishdate, content, tags, url, self.tableName, url)
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

Comment: insert...values..from is not valid syntax insert..select..from is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ) at the end of EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {} WHERE url={}